# Using TikZ inside a figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, captions

I have a PNG plot with a couple of black patches in it, and I'd like to refer to it in the `\caption` of the `figure`. According to the TikZ manual, I'd have to

```
\tikz \fill[black] (1ex,1ex) circle (1ex);
```

which works perfectly outside a `\caption`. Using this inside a `\caption`, though, leaves me with the compile error

```
! Use of \use@pgflibrary doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                              #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.375 ...blah blah.}

?
```

The following produces the compile error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz \fill[orange] (1ex,1ex) circle (1ex);
\begin{figure}
\caption{\tikz \fill[orange] (1ex,1ex) circle (1ex);}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any hints here?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The argument of `\caption` is a moving argument, i.e. it can also be displayed in the list of figures. It is therefore written into an external file. This does not work with *fragile* macros. See e.g. 
[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/2975)  for more details.

You can fix this by one of the following ways:

1. Use the optional argument of `\caption`:

   ```
   \caption["Short" caption without tikz code]{Long caption with tikz code}
   ```

   In this case only the short version is placed in the external file and the list of figures.
2. Add `\protect` for every macro:

   ```
   \caption{Some caption with tikz code: \protect\tikz \protect\fill[black] (1ex,1ex) circle (1ex);}
   ```
3. Define a robust macro for the TikZ code:

   ```
   % At best in the preamble:
   \DeclareRobustCommand\mytikzdot{\tikz \fill[black] (1ex,1ex) circle (1ex);}

   % later
   \caption{Some caption with tikz code: \mytikzdot}
   ```