# indexed letters inside circles

Tags: math-mode, text-manipulation, circles

I'm currently using this code

```
\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {f}}}
```

to get

[image]

I'm trying to index the function f inside the box, with say `$f_{n}$` but `\textcircled` doesn't seem to like this. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "`\textcircled` doesn't seem to like this", because

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {$f_n$}}} 
\end{document}
```

compiles fine for me. That said, it does look a bit rubbish:

[image]

You might consider a little TikZ picture for this situation. You could put the `$f_n$` inside a circular TikZ node. The node would adjust its size correctly, depending on its contents, and align correctly on the baseline of the surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}

\begin{document}
Lorem \encircle{$f_n$} ipsum \encircle{q} dolor \encircle{a} 
sit \encircle{A} amet \encircle{Hello}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you prefer to externally control the size of the node, use :
`\newcommand{\circled}[2][6pt]{\raisebox{-#1}{\tikz{\node (F) at (0,0) {#2};\draw[thick](F)\circle(#1);}}}`

Comment: how do you do the same with dashed lines?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez Replace `draw, shape=circle` with `draw, dashed, shape=circle`.

Comment: @MCMastery Could you provide an example?

Comment: @MCMastery What package or tikz library defines `\circled`? I get an 'undefined control sequence' error.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Wow. I just made a mistake... nevermind

Comment: @JohnWickerson I attempted to use it inside a caption and it did not work. It worked well outside the caption, though. Do you know where the problem can be?

Comment: For captions, adding \protect worked for me. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/using-tikz-inside-a-figure-caption