# How can I use \textcircled in equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am using the IEEE ACCESS template and in my paper, I am using the following equation code where I want to show the alphabet on the circle. How can I use it? The equation code is working but gives me a warning

> Command \textcircled invalid in math mode on input line 189.

How can I remove this warning?

```
\newcommand*\tcircle[1]{\textcircled{\raisebox{-0.5pt}{\fontsize{7pt}{0}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{#1}}}}

\begin{equation} 
  \begin{split}
    \tilde \uptau &=T_{\tcircle{A},i}-T_1
  \end{split}
  \label{eq9}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. It would be much easier for us to help you with the problem if you give us a Minimal Working Example from `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}` and ending with `\end{document}` that recreates the problem

Comment: Also, you should consider this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123926/90297

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `\textcircled` inside the `\raisebox` command. As the error message says, `\textcircled` has to be used in text mode, not math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\tcircle[1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5pt}{%
    \textcircled{\fontsize{7pt}{0}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont #1}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\[T_{\tcircle{A},i}-T_1\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mix of packages including `harmony` and `scalerel` to decrease or increase the text-circle "symbol" to have a good subscript, with this new macro, different from the original of the OP,

```
\newcommand{\lcirc}[1]{\scaleobj{.6}{\mbox{\Kr{#1}}}}
```

you can obtain this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{harmony}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\lcirc}[1]{\scaleobj{.6}{\mbox{\Kr{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\[T_{\lcirc{A},i}-T_1\]
\[T_{\lcirc{a},i}-T_1\]
\[T_{\lcirc{B},i}-T_1\]
\[T_{\lcirc{W},i}-T_1\]
\end{document}
```

... with this output that have the same font into the circle:

[image]