# PGF plotmarker in figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions

I want to add PGF plotmarkers to the caption of a Tikz figure. I defined commands to plot these markers like

```
\def\showpgfcircle{\tikz[baseline=-0.9ex]\node[blue,mark size=0.7ex]{\pgfuseplotmark{o}};}
```

That works well within a text (although I have a spacing problem after the marker), but within a caption it won't compile. Do you have any suggestions?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    positioning,
    calc,
    circuits.ee.IEC,
    external,
    plotmarks}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units}    

\pgfplotsset{ every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}, every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize,text depth=.25ex}}
%set labels in all diagrams in scriptsize

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={ }}
% use comma for dezimal numbers; no use of thoudends seperator

\def\showpgfcircle{\tikz[baseline=-0.9ex]\node[blue,mark size=0.7ex]{\pgfuseplotmark{o}};}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]    % Example plot with markers
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[scale=1]
    \pgfsetplotmarksize{0.7ex}
    \addplot[draw=blue,mark=o, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { 
    (0.041457198, -0.56082138) (-0.46495696, -0.31631368) (-0.50641416, 0.2445077) (-0.041457198, 0.56082138) (0.46495696, 0.31631368) (0.50641416, -0.2445077) (-0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, -0.73772534) (-0.42592593, -0.73772534) 
    };
    \addplot[draw=red,mark=x, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { 
    (0.041457198, -0.56082138) (-0.46495696, -0.31631368) (-0.50641416, 0.2445077) (-0.041457198, 0.56082138) (0.46495696, 0.31631368) (0.50641416, -0.2445077) (-0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, -0.73772534) (-0.42592593, -0.73772534)
    };
    \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example caption. I want to add the marker here.}
\end{figure}

Example text with PGFmarker like \showpgfcircle included. This works, but there is no space after the marker.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've gotten an answer, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/using-tikz-inside-a-figure-caption and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands

Comment: Also, you can add a `\label{blueplot}` after the `\addplot` command, and get the marker with `\ref{blueplot}`. Albeit maybe in a smaller size.

Comment: I tried it first with \label and \ref , but this didn't work and I don't know why, so I tried to fix it with my own commands.

Comment: @Daniel See this question:
 [tikz legend in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20926/30280) :)

Comment: @hooy Yes, I found that thread before asking my question. I tried this solution, as it is basically really simple. But it produced errors while compiling. And I couldn't really figure out why. I'll probably try it with a MWE when I have time, but for now I'm satisfied with the working solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was almost correct. Only two things missing.

First, the lack of space you mentioned is because TeX eats spaces after a macro name (see chapter 3 of the TeXBook, its very short and explains a lot). You have to enforce a space after the macro with `\⍽` (`⍽` indicates a normal space).

Additional note: There is the [`xspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace?lang=en) package, that performs various checks and tries to determine whether a space should or should not be inserted after the macro name, so you should not need to worry about typing `\⍽` after the macro name. But before you use it, see the [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace).

If you opt to use `xspace`, the your macro becomes:

```
\def\showpgfcircle{\tikz[baseline=-0.9ex]\node[blue,mark size=0.7ex]{\pgfuseplotmark{o}};\xspace}
```

and you use it with:

```
The macro \showpgfcircle will insert a space in the first case, but not here: \showpgfcircle.
```

---

Second, to add a `tikzpicture` to the caption you have to `\protect` it because the figure caption is written to the .lof file to create the list of figures. See [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect) and [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands).

Here is your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    positioning,
    calc,
    circuits.ee.IEC,
    external,
    plotmarks}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units}    

\pgfplotsset{ every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}, every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize,text depth=.25ex}}
%set labels in all diagrams in scriptsize

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={ }}
% use comma for dezimal numbers; no use of thoudends seperator

\def\showpgfcircle{\tikz[baseline=-0.9ex]\node[blue,mark size=0.7ex]{\pgfuseplotmark{o}};}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]    % Example plot with markers
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[scale=1]
    \pgfsetplotmarksize{0.7ex}
    \addplot[draw=blue,mark=o, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { 
    (0.041457198, -0.56082138) (-0.46495696, -0.31631368) (-0.50641416, 0.2445077) (-0.041457198, 0.56082138) (0.46495696, 0.31631368) (0.50641416, -0.2445077) (-0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, -0.73772534) (-0.42592593, -0.73772534) 
    };
    \addplot[draw=red,mark=x, only marks, is smithchart cs] coordinates { 
    (0.041457198, -0.56082138) (-0.46495696, -0.31631368) (-0.50641416, 0.2445077) (-0.041457198, 0.56082138) (0.46495696, 0.31631368) (0.50641416, -0.2445077) (-0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, 0.73772534) (0.42592593, -0.73772534) (-0.42592593, -0.73772534)
    };
    \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example caption. I want to add the marker here: \protect\showpgfcircle\ see? }
\end{figure}

Example text with PGFmarker like \showpgfcircle\ included. This works, but there is no space after the marker.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the references, I'll make sure to read them! And thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome. See my comment about the `xspace` package.