# Is it possible to insert an image **IN** a caption itself?

Tags: graphics, captions

So I am writing my thesis in LaTeX for bioengineering, and I have an image of a genetic circuit like so:

[image]

And I want the caption to read like this:

Fig 2.1. Genetic circuit 0x8E. This is a circuit diagram of the circuit 0x8E from the Cello paper. IPTG, aTc and Ara are the input mole.. blah... **In where (*image of a NAND gate*) represents a NAND gate, (*image of a AND gate*) represents an AND gate, and ([image]) represents a NOT gate.**

Is it possible to add mini-images in the caption itself of an image in LaTeX?

Comment: You can try [using TikZ in the caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/using-tikz-inside-a-figure-caption), though it's a little tricky (see the accepted answer).

Comment: In addition to the tricks mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/using-tikz-inside-a-figure-caption), you could just use a `\savebox`.