# Tikz picture inside a caption throws errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, captions

I get errors thrown at me because of this kind of expression

```
\begin{figure}
    \caption{\( a = \begin{tikzpicture} \node at (0,0) {a}; \end{tikzpicture} \)}
\end{figure}
```

What shall I do to use a Tikz picture inside caption?

Comment: `\caption{\( a = \protect\tikz{\protect\node at (0,0) {a};} \)}` see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/using-tikz-inside-a-figure-caption

Comment: Yes it does. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to have helped you :)

Comment: Thanks CarLaTeX, I am happy there are people like you around :-)